# sql - display the span of days given dates(date_start and date_end), if the end_date is over the penalty is applied

Tags: php, mysql, date, sum

help me revise my code.
this is my sql code:

```
    SELECT lt.loan_amount, lt.rel_date, lt.due_date,
    DATEDIFF( lt.rel_date, lt.due_date ) AS span, 
    (((DATEDIFF( lt.due_date, lt.rel_date )) + curdate()) * 0.02) AS penalty
    FROM loan_transaction lt, members m
    WHERE lt.MID = m.MID
```

but the output is a mess. I just wanted to mean with this that when the due_date is over, the 0.02 penalty will apply.

```
    (((DATEDIFF( lt.due_date, lt.rel_date )) + curdate()) * 0.02) AS penalty..
```

how will i show this in php mysql?
I new to this. i'm actually struggling with this.
Pls help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how exactly you like to put penalty, like on daily basis or one time, but you can use [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
SELECT lt.loan_amount, lt.rel_date, lt.due_date,
    DATEDIFF( lt.rel_date, lt.due_date ) AS span, 
    IF(DATEDIFF(lt.due_date, lt.rel_date) > 0, 0.02, 0) AS penalty
    FROM loan_transaction lt, members m
    WHERE lt.MID = m.MID
```

This is considering you are trying to compare due_date with rel_date for considering penalty. This will return penalty as 0.02 if due_date is greater than rel_date.

If you want to compare it with today's date, you can use

`IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), lt.due_date) > 0, 0.02, 0) AS penalty`

This will return penalty as 0.02 if today's date is greater than due_date.

Edit: To apply penalty of 0.02 for each day after due_date, you should use following:

`IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), lt.due_date) > 0, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), lt.due_date)*0.02, 0) AS penalty`

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. Yes its on a daily basis. This helps. Thank you. how about if example my rel_date is (2015-02-26) and due-date is (2015-03-26). how would i apply the penalty?  i am going to apply the penalty after 2015-03-26. Thank you for the help.

Comment: thank you so much. i got it. i cant up vote because it needs 15 reputation and i only got six. thank you so much for the help

Comment: well, that's fine. But you can accept answer if it helped!